# Show that $K[X^2,X^3]\subset K[X]$ induces an isomorphism between the quotient fields

Tags: ring-theory

To show that there is an isomorphism between $Q(K[X^2,X^3])$ and $Q(K[X])$, can I just take the mapping

$\Psi: Q(K[X^2,X^3]) \rightarrow Q(K[X])$  with $\Psi(\frac{a}{b}) = \frac{a}{b}$ ?

Comment: Yes you can send every element to 'itself', this should work. The difficulty is showing surjectivity, although you should of course also show that it is an injective morphism. The difficulties that you will encounter depend on whether you wish to rely on the 'universal property' or the 'construction' of the fraction field. (Or both.)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and fiddle with it.